# Update values from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, feed

I have one activity which contains a list(similar to fb or instagram feed) and I have buttons for liking that item and it also shows number of likes. Now suppose I click on the image, it opens an exploded view of image in a separate activity which also has like button. If I do a like on the image in exploded view activity, I want to reflect the same thing on the image in previous(feed) screen. I know one way is to refresh the feed from backend on `onResume()` method of the first activity. But I don't want to refresh the whole page, lose possible scroll and disrupt user experience just for reflecting a change in UI and some variables. Is there any standard way of doing these kind of things? How does facebook or other similar apps achieve this? If there is any library which could help, do let me know that too. Thanks.

Comment: You will get exact value only if the data updated into DB. if you want to do it on offline, then you have to keep your data in any of local resource.

Comment: I don't want to maintain DB. Actually the app I am creating is kind of social app and I can't download the whole graph and save it to DB. Isn't there any hack or method that would let me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

My decision onActivityResult() + notifyDataSetChanges() my code for 10 minutes not perfect but :

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private AdapterListView adapterListView;
        private int adapterUpdateItemPosition;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayList<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ )
                list.add(new SomeObject());
            adapterListView = new AdapterListView( (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    adapterUpdateItemPosition = position;
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class), SecondActivity.REQUEST_UPDATE);
                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if (requestCode == SecondActivity.REQUEST_UPDATE){
                    adapterListView.updateListView(adapterUpdateItemPosition, data.getBooleanExtra(SecondActivity.ADAPTER_POSITION, false));
                }
            }
        }
    }

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String ADAPTER_POSITION = "ADAPTER_POSITION";
    public static final int REQUEST_UPDATE = 2321;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_grid);

        findViewById(R.id.tv_item_grid).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(ADAPTER_POSITION, true));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private ArrayList<SomeObject> objects;

    public AdapterListView(LayoutInflater lInflater, ArrayList<SomeObject> objects) {
        this.lInflater = lInflater;
        this.objects = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SomeObject getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, parent, false);
        }
        SomeObject p = getItem(position);
        if(p.isLike()) {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_grid)).setText("LIKE");
        } else  ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_grid)).setText("NOT LIKE");

        return view;
    }

    public void updateListView(int position, boolean isLike){
        getItem(position).setLike(isLike);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public class SomeObject{
    private boolean like = false;

    public boolean isLike() {
        return like;
    }

    public void setLike(boolean like) {
        this.like = like;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh the downloaded data from where the listview adapter feeds.

Then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

That way you update your data locally and refresh your list.

Is not possible to just update one row of a listview, is that what are you looking for?

Comment: I didn't understand what you have written. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Theres a difference between redownloading the data and refreshing the list to show changes. Just pointing you to the second thing and asking if you are looking for an alternative to update just a single row instead of the whole listview.

Comment: I want to just update a single row, not the whole list. And suppose I redownload the data, I replace the list object at specific index, and call notifyDataSetChanged(), but then also, redownloading the data takes some seconds and the change would not be instant.

Comment: As i know theres no way to update a single row, if you are going to redownload the data it doesnt matter if you update a single item or the whole array, the only way that comes to my mind is to update the array and wait for the listview to redraw the row on users scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`.

That way you could setup a code that implies that the user made something in the second activity that needs the first to refresh data.

Comment: even if I do that, how do I actually update that specific variable in that specific list index? And how do I communicate the changed value from exploded screen to feed screen, since I am not using an intent to start an activity(feed), I am just closing the top activity from the back stack.

Comment: you can pass the row object model to the exploded screen via intent extras, then, if you modify it, will the changes be reflected on the original object cause of java passing the object by reference or am i wrong?

Comment: Actually Java pass objects by passing a copy of the reference. I'm not sure that what Nanoc suggest works. I think Android copies the object in the intent so the changes in the received object won't be visible in the original one. Anyway, you could try it and confirm

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalBroadcastManager to send broadcast to which your previous activity will be listening.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LIST_UPDATED);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I guess, this will just tell the first(feed) activity whether the list needs to be updated or not. How do I actually transfer the value of changed variables to feed activity?

Comment: The broadcast will be wasted if previous activity gets destroyed. And it ain't the right way.

Comment: In the brodcast's intent, you can set any data that is parceleable.