# Adding date from a calendar into EditText in a different class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-calendar

I have made an application where a user can select a date on a calendar in my `Calendar.java` activity once the user selects this date I want it to put this date in an `EditText` field in a separate activity called AddDeadline. Currently I have a calendar and once the user selects that date it brings them to the separate activity called `AddDeadline.java` and brings the date up as a toaster. Is there a way that when the user selects a date that it will put that date into my `EditText` in my AddDeadline.java activity field.

My code is as fallows

Calendar.java

```
CalendarView calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender);


    calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dayOfMonth+ "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Calender.this, AddDeadline.class));
        }

    });
}
```

AddDeadline.java

```
public EditText editDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_deadline);

editDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);


            final EditText edate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            edate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

            {

                @Override
                public void onClick (View v){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //To show current date in the datepicker
                Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(AddDeadline.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;
                        edate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
            }

            );
        }
```

Comment: I suggest reading some of the answers to similar questions on this site first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309927/update-views-in-one-activity-from-another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500624/update-values-from-one-activity-to-another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643940/refresh-listview-after-updating-in-another-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do put data to intent like

```
CalendarView calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender);


    calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dayOfMonth+ "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Calender.this, AddDeadline.class)
             intent.putExtra("date", dayOfMonth+ "/" + month + "/" + year);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
```

get date in AddDeadline  class by

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
```

like

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_deadline);
    String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");

    editDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
editDate.setText(date);


}
```

Comment: Thank this worked like a charm and well explained. Marked as correct and +1.